# XML to FLF conversion

Tags: xml, parsing

i thought maybe someone here can help me get along with my struggle to convert portions of data from an xml document into a flat text file with fixed length.

Im using Altova Mapforce and getting along pretty well.
I have mapped many data portions from the source xml to two different fixed txt output documents.

Two different documents because the rows of the first document are 1-n, so it shows multiple rows with data all structured in the same way. the second txt output just shows one line in the same structure. now the content of the second document needs to follow all the lines of the first document in a third final output flf txt document.

i can achieve this very well by serializing the first two output txts and mapping them to two fields in my final output. however i cant then compile code since all but the inbuilt code dont support serializing. so cant compile to c++ or java.

does anyone have a suggestion on how to differently approach this?

thanks so much!
corebloom

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to use a program `Altova Mapforce` to map code or trying to write a program in java or c++.  I'm also not sure what is/isn't working.  Can you post samples of what you're trying to do and what is currently happening and code you have written?  We don't provide software support or write entire programs for people.

Comment: its ok lauren, no worries. i didnt want spftware support (i asked for a different way to approach) nor would i ever want someone to develope the software for me :) all good, i found smth!

Comment: In case others come by this post, can you share what you found?